# Ito's formula for square of a norm

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Consider the stochastic process $X_t=\int_{0}^{t}b_sds+\int_{0}^{t}\phi_sdW_s $, where $W_t$ is the standard weiner process and all the preconditions are satisifed by $b_t$ and $\phi_t$ so that $X_t$ is continuous semimartingale. $X:\Omega \times[0,t]\to K$, $K$ is Hilbert space. What will be the resulting process $||X_t||_{L^2}^2$ if we apply Ito formula for $F(x)=||x||_{L^2}^2$?

Comment: Is the norm the $L^2$ norm over the $t$ variable or the Hilbert norm of the range space $K$? In the second case it would be better to write $F(x)=\|x\|_K^2$.

Comment: It's $L^2$ norm

Comment: Probably you can do Ito to $\phi(x) = x^2$ using $X_t$ then take the expectation.